# Converting HTML Table into Image File

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

Is there any way to Convert HTML table to Image file? I have one HTML table which contains controls like Labels, GridView, and CheckBoxes. How can we convert this table into Image file for creating a PDF file?

Comment: You would have to simulate the rendering of your browser. Seems like a very decent task to me.

Comment: Does it need to be an image first? PDF generator should take HTML fine.

Comment: MikeSmithDev: I checked PDF generator, but didn't get the exact one.. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render HTML to an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one-off, load it up in your browser and take a screenshot (Alt-PrtScr on windows for just the current application)

If you need to do this repeatedly/in an automated way, you can either automate a [browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) or you can use a headless browser

You should also look into [WebKit2Png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) which will render the page in the same manner as Chrome/other webkit browsers and then save that as a png. It can optionally simulate javascript/etc too

Similarly, there's a [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which works on all platforms

Answer (score 2):

This is not a trivial task. Ultimately, you need an HTML renderer to convert the HTML to pixels.

Fortunately, you don't need to write your own. You can use the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx).

You can see some code I wrote to extract a thumbnail image from a given URL in the article [Creating Website Thumbnails in ASP.NET](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/graphics/creating-website-thumbnails-in-asp-net).

Comment: I've actually done something similar to create website thumbnails on-the-fly and I'd point out that the WebBrowser control requires an STA thread which can be a bit complex in multi-threaded environments. It also has a number of flaws with regards to modal dialogues never being cleared resulting in a thread waiting until it's ultimately recycled. I'm not saying not to do it, just that it has similar issues to automating office on a server

Comment: Yes, I addressed the STA issue in my article. If you found a way to avoid that, please share.

Comment: Apologies Jonathan, I skimmed and didn't spot that. I ended up doing almost exactly the same thing you did - in fact there's a chance I used your code as a reference, it looks familiar. I was using it in a multi-threaded console app which made things a little interesting and resulted in "unexplained" security warning dialogues/etc being displayed on the user desktop

Answer (score 0):

Converting HTML Table into Image File

```js
            $("#selfAssessmentPowerPointDownload").on('mouseover', function () {
                var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
                var getCanvas; // global variable
                html2canvas(element, {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        getCanvas = canvas;
                        var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                        var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
                        $("#selfAssessmentPowerPointDownload").attr("download", "gridData.png").attr("href", newData);
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<button id="selfAssessmentPowerPointDownload">Download</button>


<table id="html-content-holder"></table>
```

Comment: Is this an answer? When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 0):

[Datatables](https://datatables.net/) is a powerful jquery plugin for working with tables. One of the option that datatables offered is make a pdf or excel from your table. You can see find many examples in it's website.