# WebBrowser not running javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf, printing

I'm utilizing a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` (used in a separate .dll file)  from my `WPF` application in order to print some `HTML` content in the background.
My problem is that the HTML elemnts are not being affected by the `javascript` in the page.
I know that there are no errors in the page because that if I copy its content after the `DocumentCompleted` event and paste it into a plain HTML file the script works.
**My HTML template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
    function loaded() {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "after javascript";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loaded()">
    <h1 id="content">before javascript</h1> <!--<= This value does not change-->
</body>
</html>
```

**I use this HTML as follows:**

```
private void PrintTest()
{
    string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(curDir, "PrintDocs\\HTMLPage1.html");

    string html = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);

    HtmlPrint.Print(html);
}

public static class HtmlPrint
{
    public static void Print(string html, string documentTitle = "")
    {
        var wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser { DocumentText = html };
        wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    private static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wb = ((System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)sender);

        wb.Print();
        wb.Dispose();
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: there was a copy \ paste problem with my javascript call. fixed it but the problem remains

Comment: @Izzy I guess you mean `wb.Document.InvokeScript("loaded");` because mysteriously it works. put this as an answer for future readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebBrowser Control DocumentCompleted after iframe & Javascript completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371893/webbrowser-control-documentcompleted-after-iframe-javascript-completion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments you can call the `InvokeScript()` method from your C# code and pass in your `js` function name as which should do the trick.

```
wb.Document.InvokeScript("loaded");
```

Comment: I think the javascript executes after the DocumentCompleted event. If I have alert("HELLO!") in the page, the popup appears after the DocumentCompleted handler has finished. This caused me problems, since I wanted to access values set by javascript on the page. I ended up triggering a timer in the DocumentCompleted handler that waited a second; on the timer_tick handler, I could then grab the now populated value.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the Braces in onload:

```
<body onload="loaded()">
```

Comment: nice catch but it was just a test that I've made (I'm not that familiar with js), the results are the same in both cases

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change `onload="loaded"` to [`onload="loaded()"`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)