# How can I create an Image from html string content?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am sending mails of this html created page, but that page design is changed in outlook. so i am trying to convert this html source to image and send mails.

so I have stored html source in string variable like this.

```
string Str1 = "<table id='myTable3' style='width:100%;background-color: #4B4B4B;border:2px solid #8b8b8b;padding:0% 2% 0% 0%;margin-top:2% !important;'><tbody><tr><td style='text-align:left;padding:2% 0% 0% 2%;font-size:20px;color:#6BB6E7;font-weight:600;'></td></tr> </tbody></table>";
```

i have tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832304/convert-html-string-to-image) solution but it is not working.

so how can i convert this html source into image?

Comment: how are you sending the mail? for `System.Net.Mail`, there will be a property `IsBodyHtml` for `MailMessage` which you need to set to true to render the html properly

Comment: @Developer i have set IsBodyHtml property is true already.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question wrong. What you need is a solution to convert the dynamic html to image on the fly. prob `BitMap` should help you in this case

Answer (score 1):

Fire gimp or any other image manipulation program. Even pain will do on Widows(missing n err) and type the string. Save as png or jpeg.