# How to convert html or xml to image format without using js

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml, image

How to convert html or xml format to xml without using js as i have to make in webserive of c# asp.net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML string to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832304/convert-html-string-to-image)

Comment: yes ...dll is not working for webservice