# How do I convert an html web page into image using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-5

How to convert a dynamic link which is a html web page into an Image format. Remember the link is dynamic which contains html content in string format. I have tried a lot of ways like reading the html content using converting to base64 first then visa versa.

```
var htmlToImageConv = new HtmlToImageConverter();
 byte[] jpegBytes = htmlToImageConv.GenerateImage(html, ImageFormat.Jpeg); System.Drawing.Image image; using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(strOg))
 { 
image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms); string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/"); 
}
```

I have tried this code in c# for converting html webpage to image.

Comment: You should try adding the things you have tried to your question, this will make the question more valid, for other to repond, otherwise there is a chance its can get closed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a headless browser to render the html and then take a snapshot.

Have a look at PuppeteerSHarp: https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp

Comment: Thank uh.. I would try.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to render the page and save a screenshot as a png image.

Add the following packages to your project:

- Selenium.WebDriver
- Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver

Use the following code to save a screenshot:

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

            ss.SaveAsFile("screenshot.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but I am still having an issue. The above code is taking the screenshot of  the whole page. What happens when a user clicks on the link  the html web page opens in iframe. That iframe will have extra background with it which  I do not want to include in the screenshot. Is it possible if I can only take the screenshot of img inside iframe.

Comment: Or maybe if its possible to take the screenshot without opening the url in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

That what you need is a conversation from a html containing string to an image, which is already discussed in the answers of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832304/convert-html-string-to-image).