# Acumatica - report designer

Tags: acumatica

Can we add HTML or Right text to the report designer?

From the Below link I know it is not there, but I think with latest versions Acumatica must have added some support for it.
[Is it possible to get data from the Rich Text control and show it in an Acumatica report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844029/is-it-possible-to-get-data-from-the-rich-text-control-and-show-it-in-an-acumatic)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

No, a rich text control was not added to the report designer toolbox.
TextBox control has no rich text functionality.

Comment: Is there any work around to show the rich text

Comment: It is possible to use a third-party library or dot net framework to render the rich text content to an image and then display the image in the report. stackoverflow.com/a/17835914/7376238