# Html divs not displaying with browser print

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, printing

I am creating a graphic to be dynamically generated for a report for one of our clients. I have the rough layout and I am testing to see how it prints. However, when I go to print it/save to pdf (testing both), the stylized divs are not being displayed.

Html Generate Screen

[image]

Print/Pdf Page

[image]

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS styling for printing is very limited. With more complex layout like yours, you're either better of [converting it to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image) or [converting it to a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php). Choosing the best framework really depends on what back-end you're using. In Java I had most of luck using [FlyingSaucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) and in PHP [html2pdf](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/).

Also, [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) is good tutorial on what is possible using CSS styling for printing.