# Twitter API, get Tweet as Image

Tags: twitter

I understand you can get the specific url of a tweet using the Twitter API by creating a url like this

```
https://twitter.com/username/status/tweet-id
```

However, is it possible to get an image of a tweet?
I can get media images, but those are just images that people posted in the tweet. I want to know if it is possible to get an image of the tweet itself.

Comment: There are lots of screenshot API services - have you tried any of them?

Comment: any direct solution for this  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter's API includes the ability to do this with oembed.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed

Comment: Nice info. But this only gets the oEmbed (HTML), not an image. I've tried setting `widget_type=photo` but no effect.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to get a true image, only just the html. But if you have the html of the tweet, you could use a library like HTML2Canvas see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image to convert that HTML to the image you want. Make sure you include the CSS in your html as well. Good Luck with your endeavor!

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: Take the html and make it an image is really the only thing I can think of at this point but I haven't worked on this project in some time.

Answer (score 0):

See https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/tweets-as-an-image

This project provides an API for downloading tweets as images: [https://tweets-as-an-image.herokuapp.com/tweet?twitterHandle={your_twitter_handle}&id={your_tweet_id}&theme={light_or_dark}&maxwidth={max_width_of_your_tweet_image}&height={height_of_the_image}&lang={language}](https://tweets-as-an-image.herokuapp.com/tweet?twitterHandle=%7Byour_twitter_handle%7D&id=%7Byour_tweet_id%7D&theme=%7Blight_or_dark%7D&maxwidth=%7Bmax_width_of_your_tweet_image%7D&height=%7Bheight_of_the_image%7D&lang=%7Blanguage%7D)

Answer (score 0):

Fast forward to 2023 - none of the one above seems to be available anymore.

This library worked flawlessly for me. It is not an web API but works well and has good options:
https://github.com/Xacnio/tweetcapture

Answer (score -1):

You can now get images or screenshots of tweets using the @aissistant handle on twitter.

```
Retweet any tweet with the comment "@aissistant #image" to get an image.
Retweet any tweet with the comment "@aissistant #screenshot" to get a screenshot.
```

For other options like converting to memes and jokes check out the handle.

Full disclosure: I am creator of the bot behind the handle.