# Can you tell me if there are free ways of turning an HTML page into Image using .NET

Tags: .net, screenshot, html

So basicly, I have a code and I want to take HTML with all the text and images and turn it into an image that contains everything. Is there any free ways of doing it?  The version of .NET is 3.5

Comment: You need a headless browser

Answer (score 0):

There are a few browser extensions that do this for you.
Chrome: [Full Page Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?hl=en-US)
Firefox: [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already have seen this reference?
But it has some options for doing just this.

[Render HTML to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image)

Here is online tool to acomplish this task as well:
https://cloudconvert.com/html-to-png

Edit: Their API looks really useful and powerful. It appears you can convert many different types of formats (just not web) into many other types of formats. The API looks like a simple ajax call. There are also official wrappers and third party wrappers as well. https://cloudconvert.com/api