# Export any Chart, any table and any content into Image In Angular2 Project

Tags: jquery, html, angular2-services, export-to-image

I am working on Angular2 Project in which I've implemented below things in my project:

- jQxGrid (http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/defaultfunctionality.htm)
- Angular Table
- nvd3 boxplot chart (https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/)
- jQxDonut chart (http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm#demos/jqxchart/javascript_chart_donut_series.htm)

I would like to implement common code which can export HTML / div / table / any chart into PNG/JPEG.

Is there any easiest way to implement export functionality in Angular 2?

I have seen below links and tried to implement it but no luck.

https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image#usage

[Render HTML to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image)

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Export-HTML-DIV-or-Table-to-Image-using-HTML-Canvas-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

https://codepedia.info/convert-html-to-image-in-jquery-div-or-table-to-jpg-png/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**html2canvas** library](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) it will allow you to save any DOM portion as a Canvas:

> The script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser.

Here's an example of how would be your code:

```
html2canvas($("#widget"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    $("#img-out").html("");
    theCanvas = canvas;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    $("#img-out").append(canvas);
  }
});
```

This is [a demo **Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/ame13f5g/1/).

You can find more examples in [**html2canvas** website](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).