# Telegram Bots: Send lists of options

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to format a message sent by a telegram bot as a list?

I want to build a bot that presents the menu of a restaurant with about 20 options and sub-options (e.g., kind of meat) as a list:

```
- Spaghetti
  * Carbonara
  * Bolognese
- Ice Cream
  * additional chocolate sprinkles
```

I noticed that neither `<ul>` or `<ol>` work in `parse_mode="HTML"` and I also couldn't find any syntax in `parse_mode="MarkdownV2"`. From what I see in the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) it is currently not possible. In a similar [question on tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345960/how-do-i-send-tables-with-telegram-bot-api), ASCII text and pictures were recommended. The only other option I see is inline keyboards. None of these would work well with what I had in mind.

Does someone have a workaround for this? Or can confirm that it is indeed not possible?

Comment: Please remove the tag `python-telegram-bot`, which is for the python library with that name and not relevant here ;)

Comment: I would prefer a solution that leverages the python-telegram-bot, as that is what I am also using. But you are right, it is not per se a python-telegram-bot problem. Tag is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or can confirm that it is indeed not possible?

The documentation you linked already confirmes that there are no special formatting options for (nested) lists supported by the Bot API.