# Python Telegram URL in Table

Tags: python, formatting, telegram, python-telegram-bot, prettytable

I want my Telegram bot to send a message that has a formatted table with links inside. I am using [prettytable module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67120975/2893712) as a basis to create a table. Here is what my `table` variable looks like:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                Name               |  Arrival   |                                                                                      Link                                                                                     |
+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|             Package #1            | 2022-08-06 |    [1Z1234567890](https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=1Z1234567890&requester=WT/trackdetails) \| [AS](https://somewebsite.com/1Z1234567890)    |
|             Package #2            | 2022-08-07 |    [1Z9876543210](https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=1Z9876543210&requester=WT/trackdetails) \| [AS](https://somewebsite.com/1Z9876543210)    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And then I send the table with:

````
update.message.reply_text(f'```{table}```', parse_mode='MarkdownV2', disable_web_page_preview=True)
````

but the URLs show up as the markdown code (because of the ```` ``` ```` tags).

Is there a way to send this formatted table but have the links show up as links?

Comment: You can't have text link entities, neither URLs inside a `\`\`\``, nor `\``.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get TG to send nicely formatted tables is a lost cause. Even with monospaced text, the line width depends on the client, device, font, font size etc. So it's almost sure that there is an additional line break for *someone* reading the message, which messes up the table formatting.

If you want to send a nice table, send it as document, picture, HTML file or something similar.