# PHP: HTML to PNG serverside?

Tags: php

I have some generated stuffs (graphs/tables), what's size is variing.

I need a tool what converts it to jpg or png server side and only the data and can be usable with `php`.

I tried `wkhtmltoimage`, `phantomjs` and `mink` too, but they captures the whole screen.

I will use this table for testing:

```
<div class="capturable">
    <table>
        <tr><td>This is one of my tables</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes becouse I have to send the image as an email attachement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using mPDF or TCPDF to easily convert the table to PDF and then simply convert pdf to png/jpg.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try :D

Comment: By the way, before you go into such drastic methods, maybe you should take a look at https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image it was directed at this problem. But I doubt that there is other ways to do it with PHP, only with js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image

Comment: i do this on a regular basis server-side with TCPDF ... dont forget to read the small print (tldr; GNU Lesser GPL), and it can guzzle up quite a bit of cpu , just like guzzle.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you can call the js on the click of the event which initiates the email.

You can use [HTML to Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

You just need to include the JS https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js into your html.

Then you can use the below script

```
html2canvas(jQuery(".main-content"), {
 useCORS: true,
 onrendered: function(canvas) {
 theCanvas = canvas;
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);
 dataOverview = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
 uploadImage(dataOverview);//this is custom build function 
}});
```

.main-content is the selector for the section you want to convert into image

You can use it in a function or you can call it on document ready

```
function uploadImage(dataOverview)
{
    if(dataOverview)
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'ajax url to post image data',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                dataOverview:  dataOverview,
            },
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response.code == 200)
                {
                    //perform your action on success
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Once the content of the image is sent to PHP you can write it to a file using below code

```
$dataOverview = $_POST['dataOverview'];
$dataOverviewData=substr($dataOverview, strpos($dataOverview, ",")+1);
$dataOverviewunencodedData=base64_decode($dataOverviewData);
$rand = rand();
$dataOverViewfname_png = $rand.'.png';
$dataOverimgfile_png='path to the directory where you want to save the image';
$imagegerated=file_put_contents($dataOverimgfile_png, $dataOverviewunencodedData);
```

This will generate a png image of the html element which you have passed in the selector.

This is a working code as i have been using it already in some of my projects.

OR if you want to convert raw html to Image you can use the below code

```
<?php
require 'pdfcrowd.php';

try
{
    // create the API client instance
    $client = new \Pdfcrowd\HtmlToImageClient("your_username", "your_apikey");

    // configure the conversion
    $client->setOutputFormat("png");

    // run the conversion and write the result to a file
    $client->convertFileToFile("/path/to/MyLayout.html", "MyLayout.png");
}
catch(\Pdfcrowd\Error $why)
{
    // report the error
    error_log("Pdfcrowd Error: {$why}\n");

    // handle the exception here or rethrow and handle it at a higher level
    throw $why;
}

?>
```

[PDFCROWD](https://pdfcrowd.com/doc/api/)

Hope it helps you