# Screenshot of a webapp

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a webapp which will make SVG's editable

In my main div i have lot of svg's , i am trying something like google sheets , but is there anyway I can take a screenshot of the slide. like whenever i move a svg i need the screenshot to be updated

I tried using thi library http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
But it is not giving perfect output , for example i have video tag in my div it is not getting a screenshot of it

this library https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image has the same issue too

and i tried the following answer
[Render HTML to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image)
but it takes 30 seconds to take one screenshot. my screenshots will be updated for every change
so this is too long process and even it freezes my app.

Please help me out or give any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try PhantomJs : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs

It has a screen capture feature : http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: it needs to be run in server in order to capture screenshot