# How can I convert html page into image (any format), without using any external library in javascript (react)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a webpage and I need it in an image format. Can anyone tell me how to do it from scratch without using any external library ?

Comment: Just found something,that might help you .

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-div-using-javascript/

Comment: @NihalChandwani read the actual question title.

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46243263/14146108.......... might help you