# Convert HTML to a PNG Image

Tags: javascript, html, image

Libraries like `html2canvas` take HTML and convert it to a `canvas` element. Then `toDataURL()` can be used to get a URL (`data:image/png...`). So, is there a way to convert HTML to an actual PNG Image in the browser (not the `data` url)? I don't want the user to download it, just get a PNG (so that if I save that to a file, I can open the image directly). PNG or JPEG or any small image storing format can be used. My target is modern browsers (not IE).

**EDIT**

I want to take images of the HTML, convert them to PNG and then *combine* them client-side (using ffmpeg.wasm), not just display the images. Most of the answers and suggestions on StackOverflow tell you how to *display* the images using the `image.src` attribute. It doesn't *have* to be a PNG, just any format that `ffmpeg.wasm` can support (though PNG is preferred)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image This may help

Comment: A data URL can be saved to disk as a "real" image.
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file

Comment: @Lakshya Yeah I saw that question, but my options are client side only and `html2canvas` is not really the solution...

Comment: @line-o That lists out the ways to *download* the file whereas I want to *get the PNG* content of the file!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the data url in the src attribute.

```html
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7" 
width="16" height="14" alt="embedded folder icon">
```