# Upload div as an image to Google Drive via API

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-api

I'm trying to run javascript code to ensure that the div content is uploaded as PNG to the user's Google Drive.

I've already managed to start uploading to Drive via input [type = "file"] - so I know the upload is working properly. Now, however, I would need to ensure that the user does not select a file from his local storage, but that the contents of the div element are stored on his Drive.

I tried it with the following code, but it gives me the following error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toBlob is not a function.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('preview');

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
var file = document.createElement('img'),
url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var upload = new Upload(file);
upload.doUpload();
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

I believe that there is a better option than to deal with it through blob, but so far I have not been able to come up with anything like that.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Now, however, I would need to ensure that the user does not select a file from his local storage, but that the contents of the div element are stored on his Drive.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Okay, I'll try to simplify it.After clicking the "Save to Google Drive" button, the content of a particular div will be saved as a PNG to the user's Google Drive.
What I've accomplished is that I can upload a user's file on his computer to his Google Drive. But I still can't figure out how to save div content in PNG format to his Google Drive.

Comment: @Tanaike Did I explain it correctly?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanike Ok, so I will try to simplify it once more. Click "Save to Google Drive" button -> HTML div saved to user's Google Drive as a PNG file. doUpload() function is working, my problem is: DIV -> File object. I have used code from: https://codingshiksha.com/how-to-upload-files-to-google-drive-in-javascript-using-google-drive-rest-api-v3 , but it is working just with file from INPUT.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But I really apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @JanStavic It sounds to me like you're trying to render a <div> into an image file.  If that's the case, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image) might be helpful for you.  Once you have the html as an image, uploading to Google API will be reasonably straightforward using the APIs you've already discovered.