# How to add a image that use .html format in using img tag(Without using iframe or embed)

Tags: html

hi fiends i'm currently working on a project and i made a img tag that can display .html format urls without iframe how ever accidentally i removed it.anyone know to add a .html link to img tag..

I want to add this advertisement using img tag not with embed or iframe!

pls help!

advertisement-https://s0.2mdn.net/dfp/370694/5128031207/1646966699597/970x250/index.html

not working code of mine

```
<div class="container mb-3">
    <div class="row">           
        <div class="col-12 ads-parent-responsive d-none d-xl-block d-lg-block d-md-none d-sm-none">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img type="image/jpg" class="d-block w-100 image" src="https://s0.2mdn.net/dfp/370694/5128031207/1646966699597/970x250/index.html" style="width: 1100px; height: 200px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of Render [HTML to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image) ?

Comment: it's not useful